Why don't we include diagrams with fermion and gauge boson external lines while calculating the effective potential of Standard model?
While calculating the effective potential of Higgs boson, we aim at $V_{eff}(h)$ instead of $V_{eff}(h, W^{+}, W^{-}, Z, quarks, leptons)$. I think the true vacuum should be the minimum of this multivariable function rather than $V_{eff}(h)$. Why is it legal to consider $V_{eff}(h)$, which means discarding the diagrams with fermion and gauge boson external lines?

As a Lorentz-invariant Lagrangian does not necessarily imply a Lorentz invariant ground state of the theory, Lorentz invariance might, in principle,  be spontaneously broken just as well as an internal symmetry (the former being a quite common situation in condensed matter physics).
However, in particle physics, there is presently no experimental evidence that the vacuum state would single out a preferred frame of reference. Therefore, theoretical models in particle physics usually assume a Lorentz invariant ground state $|0\rangle$, implying  $\langle 0 |J^\mu(x)|0\rangle =0$ for all vector operators $J^\mu(x)$, as otherwise $\langle 0 |J^\mu(x) |0\rangle \ne 0$ would single out a certain direction in space-time. For the same reason, one assumes $\langle 0 |T^{\mu \nu}(x) |0\rangle =\eta^{\mu \nu} \langle 0|T^{\alpha}_{\; \,\alpha}(x)|0\rangle/4 $. A tensor operator $T^{\mu \nu}(x)$ does not transform irreducibly under Lorentz transformations: $T^\alpha_{\; \, \alpha}$ represents an invariant subspace, transforming as a scalar field, whereas the vacuum expectation value of the traceless part, $T^{\mu \nu}-\eta^{\mu \nu} T^\alpha_{\; \, \alpha}/4$, is assumed to vanish. As all local operators may be decomposed in an analogous manner, only scalar (or pseudoscalar) operators may give rise to order parameters in a theory with a Lorentz invariant ground state. This fact explains the focus on the effective potential containing only spin $0$ fields.
